# Is it possible to achieve 'not contains' logic using vstest TestCaseFilter?

Tags: visual-studio, vstest

I am using vstest TestCaseFilter for running selective unit tests in VS 2013.

My goal is to to run all tests with categories that do **not** contain a certain string.

From what I have read so far ([here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vikramagrawal/archive/2012/07/23/running-selective-unit-tests-in-vs-2012-rc-using-testcasefilter.aspx)), the operators that are supported are:

```
= (equals)
!= (not equals)
~ (contains or substring only for string values)
& (and)
| (or)
( ) (paranthesis for grouping)
```

Filtering all categories which contain a string is trivial but how do I achieve the opposite?

Could not figure a way to achieve this so far...

Comment: I'm having the same question. Did you find an answer?

Comment: @cremor I'm facing the same problem. Did you happen to find any solutions for this?

Comment: @mbdevpl No, this is still an open question for me.

Comment: What about now? Any updates? I wanted exactly a "not contains" for my scenario.

Comment: @julealgon I have not a found a solution for this yet. Maybe it is not possible...

Comment: Yep, after struggling with this one a bit, I opened [an issue to request this feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1385).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature has been added to VSTest recently (See the PR [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/pull/1803)) using `!~`.  However, it doesn't seem to be available until VS2019 (I get errors trying to use it in VS2017.9, but it works in VS2019).